# Excel Macro to update macro

Tags: excel, vba

I have a scenario. I am using a set of excel files for reporting. All of these excels are macro enabled and have a "login" function to connect to server. To fix the security issue, we have to update "login" function.
Is there a way to write a macro to replace this function in all such excel files? basically a macro to update a macro!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Enable macro security option:

[image]

Then you need a code like this:

```
Sub AddMacro()

    Dim xlbook As Workbook
    Set xlbook = ActiveWorkbook 'Assign workbook to have macro added here

    Dim xlmodule As Object
    Set xlmodule = xlbook.VBProject.VBComponents.Add(1)

    Dim strCode As String
    strCode = _
       "Function MyFunction()" & vbCr & _
       "'some function code here" & vbCr & _
       "End Function"
    xlmodule.CodeModule.AddFromString strCode

End Sub
```

Comment: Good luck trying to convince your network admin to trust access to the VBA project object model on all workstations!

Answer (score 0):

I have had a similar problem in the past. Basically needed to update functions when new rates came in, to all users.

My solution was to use .xlam files, basically push the updates when users reboot their computers.

If you don't have multiple users, simply having the macro a module in the "PERSONAL.XLSB", will simply require updating that macro, which would then work on every workbook.